# Use Cambria Math as default font

Tags: luatex, fontspec, overleaf

I am trying to use Cambria Math with font size 14 as the default text (for the math text I am fine with either the default Latex font or Cambria Math). I switched from pdflatex to Luatex (because pdflatex does not support Cambria Math). I am using overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document} 
$a + b$
This is a test
\end{document}
```

When I run this in Overleaf I get the following errors both of which occur at \begin{document}

1. Package fontspec Error: The font "CambriaMath" cannot be found
2. Font \TU/CambriaMath(0)/m/n/10=CambriaMath:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.

The equation $a+b$ shows on the document but the text "This is a test" does not.

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf helpdesk about the issue of not being able to load `Cambria Math`? Their LaTeX support staff is top notch.

Comment: Cambria math is not licensed for use outside Windows and overleaf use Linux servers. so it is not installedi and you can't upload a copy to your project without breaking the license agreement

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answered in comments